# Tax filing requirements for inactive LLC filing as S Corp

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company

I have a single member LLC that files as an S Corp. In 2023 it was inactive. I know that I have to file an 1120-S. I'll be putting zeroes for all the dollar amounts.

Do I need to complete the various schedules that come with the 1120-S or can I just do the first page?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Schedule B](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1120s#en_US_2023_publink1000287486) and [Schedule K](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1120s#en_US_2023_publink11515kd0e3929) are required, and others may be needed depending on the situation.